# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isAtLeastR()Z

Tags: android, gmail-api

My app was running fine but suddenly I started getting this error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isAtLeastR()Z in class Landroidx/core/os/BuildCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.os.BuildCompat' appears in /data/app/com.app.goflatmates-RZKwS2h6hav==/base.apk)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.util.PlatformVersion.isAtLeastR(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.0:21)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.0:128)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.0:23)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.0:54)
>           at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.(Unknown Source:3)
>           at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getClient(Unknown Source:3

**The problem is coming in this line**

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build(); 

mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

Comment: Somehow, the `androidx.core.os.BuildCompat` from compile and execution disagree.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had this issue with React Native as well. I fixed it by setting this in my app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
    // ...
}
```

It's because of a breaking change introduced by Google play-services-base library a couple days ago. If you use `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+'` it will download the latest version of the library, introducing that bug into your app. Hope that helps.

Comment: It's curious that this problem just happens on Android 10. Older versions were working fine. But changing to the specific version did the trick for all versions.

Comment: Yeah. They also didn't really document what they changed so you don't know until your app throws an error.

Comment: Some issue is there with v 17.2.0. Downgrading to v17.1.0 saved my day.
New update v17.2.1 also seems to work

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
     * Checks if the device is running on a pre-release version of Android R or newer.
     * <p>
     * <strong>Note:</strong> This method will return {@code false} on devices running release
     * versions of Android. When Android R is finalized for release, this method will be deprecated
     * and all calls should be replaced with {@code Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R}.
     *
     * @return {@code true} if R APIs are available for use, {@code false} otherwise
     */
    public static boolean isAtLeastR() {
        return VERSION.CODENAME.length() == 1 && VERSION.CODENAME.charAt(0) >= 'R'
                && VERSION.CODENAME.charAt(0) <= 'Z';
    }
```

Android Q is a finalised release and this method is no longer necessary. It
will be removed in a future release of the Support Library.

Kindly downgrade version

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0' //OR
```

Answer (score 2):

The bug was in `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.0` The previous answers saying to downgrade to 17.1.0 were correct, but Google has fixed the issue now, so you can upgrade to 17.2.1 and it also works fine.

These three were updated together, so bump them all up if you're using them:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1
com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.2.1
com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.2
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting this in my app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the same error as described by @jaymin occurs after I build apk.

My error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xxx, PID: 11111
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method loadImage$default(Landroid/widget/ImageView;Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;ZLkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;ZILjava/lang/Object;)V in class Lcom/...; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.xxx.xxx.android.commonui.GlideModuleKt' appears in /data/app/~~NHbxxxx_xxxxw==/com.xxx-kxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMA==/base.apk!classes8.dex)
```

(Before that the app works perfectly fine). To fix it I have cleared the cache (build, idea, gradle in project and under ...user/.gradle), re-install apps and Android Studio - all that for nothing.

Eventually, I have renamed the method mentioned in the error (e.g. `loadImage to loadImageTwo and back to loadImage`) and run the app.
App works. I have created apk and still all was good with the new name (`loeadImageTwo`). Afterwards, I have renamed the method back (`loadImage`) and repeated the steps, all works like a charm now.

I took me a while to figure it out so it will be worth my time if that helps someone else too.