# App keep crashing after update "play-services-base" 17.1.0 to 17.2.0 in Android SDK 29

Tags: android, firebase, sdk, google-play-services, firebase-performance

I have updated Android SDK 28 to 29 and update google play dependency `"com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0"` TO `"com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.0"`. 
When I am trying to run app and it's keep crashing. 
But if I change version to `17.1.0` then it's working fine.
Log given below. TIA.

```
2020-03-25 15:28:37.998 6632-6707/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-16-thread-1
Process: com.shohoz.rides.stage, PID: 6632
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isAtLeastR()Z in class Landroidx/core/os/BuildCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.os.BuildCompat' appears in /data/app/com.shohoz.rides.stage-AaRQwnY2Dls36TLm52LoRw==/base.apk)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.PlatformVersion.isAtLeastR(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.0:21)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.0:128)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.0:41)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.0:56)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.clearcut.zze.<init>(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.clearcut.zze.zzb(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.clearcut.ClearcutLogger.anonymousLogger(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zzf.zzbt(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.5:55)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zzf.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.5:195)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zze.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.5:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is bug in new release of Google Play Services. note crashing method `isAtLeastR` - `R` is currently in development (API30) - and this crash happens only on Android 10 (`Q`, API29)

stay with 17.1.0 and wait for 17.2.1 or never :)

edit: your question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60812702/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-isatleastrz)...