# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isAtLeastS()Z in class

Tags: java, android-studio, build.gradle, android-12

App is getting crash after I have upgraded my targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 31.
I have tried all the answers in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60812702/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-isatleastrz) but still facing same issue .
Everytime i try to open the app this error is coming

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isAtLeastS()Z in class Landroidx/core/os/BuildCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.os.BuildCompat' appears in /data/app/~~6PPcQbptT87_5h04ffIgXg
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ran in a very similar bug. There are two options out of my understanding:

- Remove that static method from that interface
- Set the minimum SDK to 24

I'm still not sure why that happens. However [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6784#issuecomment-1091487256) is one guess:

> Support for static interface methods in Android was introduced in API 24. To facilitate backward-compatibility for Android projects with Minimum Version or TargetVersion set lower than 24, the Android build tools (d8 maybe?) extract all the static methods of the interface into a separate class (similar to how the Xamarin binding tools generate an additional class for interfaces that contain static methods), whose name is name of the interface + "$-CC", and modifies the calling code to call the static methods in that class instead.